# SG3525A power supply suggestion

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Today I have an old switching power supply to be repaired based on the circuit SG3525A, which the bridge rectifier and all the transistors are exploded (2 MOSFET IRF740 and 2 BJT BD135). The problem is that is repaired by another repairer and following that I'm not sure of this repair, I ask you if you can confirm the type of the 2 command transistors: Q6 and Q7 if they are NPNs like schema or PNPs, and what is the exact role of Q6 and Q7 in this configuration.
in the same case, and basing with the value of the mosfet IRF740 and the output diode BYV72, what is the best value for the bridge rectifier BR.
thank you for 'advance.

[image: SG3525A]

Comment: Are you saying that you don't trust the schematic in your question?

Comment: The entire gate driving circuit looks quite odd to me. Could you double-check that you traced it correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have verified it many times so I suppose I have traced it correctly